# Can't change the values of multiselect with ant design and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, multi-select, antd

I have a multiselect developed with [ant Design](https://ant.design/components/select/) which his values is fetched from the backend :

```
 "jours": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "jour": "Lundi"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "jour": "Mardi"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "jour": "Mercredi"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "jour": "Jeudi"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "jour": "Vendredi"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "jour": "Samedi"
        }
    ]
```

My code is :

```
    jour:[], jours:[], joursId:[], 
handleJourChange = (jour) => { 
    this.state.jours.map((jourId)=>{
      this.state.joursId.push(""+jourId.id+"");
      this.setState({
        joursId: this.state.joursId
      })
      console.log(this.state.joursId)
      if (jour.includes('all')) {
        this.setState({ jour: this.state.joursId });
      } 
      else {
        this.setState({jour :jour});
      }
    })
  }

<Select id="motif" name= "motif" mode="multiple" showArrow allowClear showSearch style={{ width: '535px' }} placeholder="Sélectionnez le(s) motif(s)" value={this.state.jour} onChange={this.handleJourChange} 
                                optionFilterProp="children" filterOption={(input, option) => option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0}>
                          <Option value="all">Sélectionner tout</Option>
                          { this.state.id_user > 0 && this.state.jours.map((jour)=>
                            <Option key={jour.id} value={jour.id}>{jour.jour}</Option>
                          )}
                        </Select>
```

My codeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/async-meadow-2clz5

When I run it :

- The option of select is the id not the values of the data.
- When I click on select all, all values will be selected and I clear it, it will be cleared, but when I reselect all, it will be selected all multiple times, which I can't cleared it.

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be implemented by changing the `handleChange` functionality to:

```
handleJourChange = jour => {
  if (jour.includes("all")) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      jour: prevState.jours.map(item => item.id)
    }));
  } else {
    this.setState({
      jour
    });
  }
};
```

There is some extra code involving `joursId` in your codesandbox that I'm not sure of.
[Full CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so56237825-dpb55)